# Ubuntu 16.10 ties all my audio jacks to ONE device, I'd like to separate the front and the back ones if possible

Tags: sound, 16.10, headphones

Basically, the front port and the back port do the same thing (and it's currently only coming out of the front port). Can I change this behavior? I switch between speakers and headphones quite regularly in Windows 10 without issue.